# How to clear ListView, it just adds new content after old content in Android App?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Please can I get abit of advice.

I am trying to get content into a ListView in Android.

I pass in an ArrayList type String, set up an adapter to pass in that content, then pass the adapter to the listView.

The problem arises in the fact that the content does display, but when I run the activity ever time the new content is just listed on top of the old content. e.g.

**Activity Name**

```
item 1
item 2
---------
item 1 //repeats again but with new content
item 2
item 3
```

I have tried:

```
list.setAdapter(null);
arrayAdapter.clear();
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();;
```

None of these seem to work. Force closing the application **does** draw in the right content though.

Any questions please ask.

```
public void fillListView(){


        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                StartSearch.myList22 );              //fill adapter with content


        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);    //feed data to listview
    }
```

This method runs every time the activity is opened by the way in order to refresh content.

Comment: you need to clear `StartSearch.myList22` array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your

```
 StartSearch.myList22 as a Global variable and
```

-->  When you get new data try above answer with your list like below code:-

```
 StartSearch.myList22.clear();
 StartSearch.myList22.addall(NewList);
```

--> if it still doesnt work try below code :-

```
 StartSearch.myList22.clear();
 StartSearch.myList22.addall(NewList);
 arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            StartSearch.myList22 ); 
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

-THANKS!~!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, let me be more specific.
I think you don't have to set adapter to null and clear it

You can change the array list you set to the adapter like

```
yourList.clear();
yourList.add(data);
```

Once your data set change then call:

```
 yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```